# Debian Bookworm exhibit a slow response when waking up after sleep

Tags: debian, kde

My PC running Debian-Bookworm takes like 20 seconds to wake up after I reactivate it via keyboard or power button. During that time all monitors remain black. Does anyone know how to speed the process up. I already deactivated hibernation to make sure my system is really just suspending but with no success. I'm using KDE as desktop environment, my Kernel is 6.1.0-10.
My journalctl shows only one entry and I think this has nothing to do with the problem.

```
sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb
sddm-helper[1185]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

UPDATE:
After some investigation, I found that after I press any button to wake up the system, the first log starts about 20 seconds later. So it seems to me, that somehow the hardware takes that long to wake up, but i have no clue why. Under Bullseye the wake up was much faster.